# Not able to update complication in watch OS 4

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, apple-watch-complication

I have updated my code to latest version.I have an issue regarding update complication in watch OS4.Before updation of the code its working fine.

My mobile app contains two languages english and chinese. User is able to update the app language from the app. When i first launch the watch app the complication show in the same language. but if i update the language from app then the complication language is never updated.

In the previous version of the swift, I had implemented the same functionality and that was working fine.I was using the following code for update the complication icon/text in the pervious version.

```
 func requestedUpdateDidBegin() {
    let server = CLKComplicationServer.sharedInstance()
    for complication in server.activeComplications! {
        server.reloadTimeline(for: complication)
    }
}
```

I was manually calling the above function in the previous version code. I don't know how to update the complication in the latest version and also didn't found any solution/tutorial regarding this. Please let me know if any one have any idea about this.